# Navigation bar extends to second row when translated

Tags: php, html, css

I'm building a website that is going to be displayed dynamically in either English or Spanish. When in Spanish the words are longer and cause the navigation bar to lap onto a second row.

http://bit.ly/ZZ5Waq

What code do I need to change?

Thanks!
-Cullen

EDIT: I would rather not make the font smaller. It's important that it remains the same size in English.

However I am willing to make it smaller/reduce padding in the Spanish version.

Does anyone know how to add CSS styles if the URL of the page has /es/ in it? Preferably with PHP.

Comment: What do you want to do? You can change the text size, change the width, shorten the words and add ellipses...

Comment: Isn't this just more of a styling issue than anything? Try changing font-style, font-size etc... there's probably no 'special code' that can help you with this

Comment: you could do `.menu-item {letter-spacing: 0px}` when it's spanish. BTW, nothing happens when i click on "painful intercourse" :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do lots of things to make the navbar 1 line.

1) Making a smaller `font-size` or a different font-style that has shorter character spacing.

2) As well, you can try to make the `padding` within each menu list smaller so that it will fit in.

3) Although you probably wouldnt' want to do this, you could even make the spanish version of the site have different layout width (making the width of the container larger).

There's lots of different ways, you'd just need to change up your codes and see how it looks. It might also very well be the case that you end up going with the 2 lines, or you might just find a way to shorten your menu lists.

Without posting any of your codes, it'll be difficult to help you further.

Comment: Is there a PHP command to apply CSS only if the URL has /es/ in it?

Comment: if statement will do it. I'm fairly certain you would know how if you learned the very basics of php. If you didn't, it will take a while to learn the basics so that you can work your way around it. Good luck anyways =)

Answer (score 0):

You could fix the widths of the menu items, and then having the text wrap to extra lines within each link. So the nav bar remains one line, but the buttons get deeper.

Two possible drawbacks and their solution:

**Problem:** Depending on your CSS, really long words will either break out of the fixed width, or will be forced to wrap in mid-word.

**Solution:** Accept the mid-word break, or have your translator use different, shorter words. It's possible to do that in just about any language, as long as you're not hellbent on using the exact same wording in both languages.

**Problem**: One-line nav links don't automatically adjust to the depth of two-line buttons, so your nav could look uneven if your links have borders or otherwise show their individual height.

**Solution**: Multiple.

- Make all the links a fixed height that can accomodate two lines, and
  either vertically center the type (you can use "display:table-cell;"
  to do this) or let it stay top-aligned.
- Use jQuery to measure the tallest link (or the height of the
  containing div) and make all the links the same height.

When building multilingual sites, I usually try to avoid the problem through design -- by leaving plenty of empty space in the nav bar for words to grow, and by having the translator use shorter words.

Edit:

To get the URL in PHP, use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

```
<?php $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strpos($url,'/es/')) { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .menu a { letter-spacing: 0; }
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This looks like a perfect solution! Could you add this CSS to the above? I tried it myself but nothing changed. .menu a { letter-spacing: 0; }

Comment: Updated the answer to add your CSS.